# I want to smooth the rim of my object

Tags: modeling, smooth

[image]

The faces in the edge of the objects need to be flush. I tried to use Auto smooth but it is creating weird artifacts and is not solving my issue.

Comment: Autosmooth causing artifacts may be caused by the topology of your mesh. But you can smooth parts of the object (not the whole object) by going to edit mode, selecting the face you want to smooth and pressing `W` > `Shade Smooth`.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you can always upload your file.

Comment: _Auto Smooth_ (although it sounds like it would smooth something) actually restricts smoothing to areas where the angle between face normals is below a certain angle which you can set there. It requires the faces to be set to _Shade Smooth_. Weird shading usually appears without _Auto Smooth_ (when edges supposed to be sharp are smoothed as well) or if there are problems in the geometry, like flipped faces, duplicate vertices etc. To be honest, I cannot see weird artifacts in your screenshot. It simply looks to be shaded flat. Did you right-click your object and then chose _Shade Smooth_?